# Get row count from database then convert it to a number

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I'm using classic ASP for this. My goal is to figure out how many entries have been made before "Sorry registration is full" message is shown.  I thought it would be simple just to count the number of rows in the database, but getting Type mismatch errors.  I don't care what is in the rows... just looking for a raw number.

```
Set ConnObj = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ConnObj.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=my-database-here"
ConnObj.Open

mysql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Contest"

Set HowMany = ConnObj.Execute(mysql)

if HowMany > 50 then

response.Write "Sorry registration is full"

response.end

end if
```

Much appreciation in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Execute` returns a `RecordSet`, not an `Integer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms807027.aspx#workshp2_topic4).

```
Set rs = ConnObj.Execute(mysql)
Set Howmany = rs(0)

if HowMany > 50 then
```

However, note that this solution doesn't really address concurrency.

Say that you currently have 49 registration... and 10 people all register at the same moment.  All 10 registrations will be given a count of 49... so you'll wind up with 59 total.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above you sometimes need to make sure your object is an integer, eg

```
if Cint(HowMany) > 50
```